# Error verifying pickled file from /.../unet/diffusion_pytorch_model.bin (Dreambooth on Colab)

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

```
Error verifying pickled file from /.../unet/diffusion_pytorch_model.bin
The file may be malicious, so the program is not going to read it.
You can skip this check with --disable-safe-unpickle commandline argument.
```

I'm trying to train a model on Google Colab using Dreambooth. I'm using Dreambooth on this model - https://civitai.com/models/132632

I ran into this error. I followed the tip and added `--disable-safe-unpickle` to my command line arguments when launching the webUI. But I still get this error.

I've tried the following:

- restarting a fresh Google Colab instance
- training dreambooth on another model
- I tried deleting `diffusion_pytorch_model.bin`, but it seems this is a necessary file for Dreambooth to run, as I get an error telling me this file is missing after I deleted it.

I don't know if this problem is because of Colab or because of something else. Any pointers?

[Link to my jupyter file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LAE0bKhZHXYwT2Q4CY3QRQB8NoVFpY6z?usp=sharing). This is a slightly modified version of [this jupyter file](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sagiodev/stablediffusion_webui/blob/master/StableDiffusionUI_ngrok_sagiodev.ipynb#scrollTo=gJBtadxGOK7b) offered by [this tutorial](https://stable-diffusion-art.com/automatic1111-colab/).